# Understanding sessions in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I read through the SQLalchemy manual about sessions, but I seem to miss something. I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "every_5min.py", line 847, in <module>
    cache()
  File "every_5min.py", line 810, in cache
    counter = harvest(harvester_date.date())
  File "every_5min.py", line 247, in harvest
     print object_already_exists.categories()
  File "/Users/X/github/app/models.py", line 747, in categories
    return [self.primary_category] + self.secondary_categories.all()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 237, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 583, in get
    value = self.callable_(state, passive)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 517, in _load_for_state
(orm_util.state_str(state), self.key)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Papers at 0x109b75190> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'primary_category' cannot proceed
```

So it seems that the object I am trying to use is not bound to a session anymore. 
I am using flask-sqlalchemy and I initiate the session when starting the app with

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

The manual seems to say that the only way how an object can become detached is if the session gets closed. But in flask-sqlalchemy the session never gets close while the app is running?
I read something about that object can expire after a commit, but I made sure that I do not commit before the error happens. Here is my actual code

```
# Get the objects
list_of_objects = db.session.query(models.Table).filter(models.Table.id.in_(list_of_ids)).all()
# there are multiple entries with this id... use the one with the highest version number
get_attr = operator.attrgetter('id')
# create a list of lists for each id
new_list = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(list_of_objects, key=get_attr), get_attr)]
get_attr = operator.attrgetter('version')
list_of_objects = [max(dummy_list, key=get_attr) for dummy_list in new_list]

# loop through a list of records
for record in root.find(OAI+'ListRecords').findall(OAI+"record"):
    # get record id
    record_id = record.find(OAI+'id')
    # check whether record already exists
    object_already_exists = next((x for x in list_of_objects if x.id == record_id), None)
    if object_already_exists:
        print object_already_exists.categories()
```

The code runs through 233 record items and then gives me the error above. Since its is always 233 I guess it is triggered by something specific, but I don't know what. As far as I understand sessions, it should keep the objects in list_of_objects bound to the session.
thanks for any advice
best carl

p.s. the category attribute is set up as

```
class Table(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    primary_category = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    ...

    secondary_categories = db.relationship('Object_Category', secondary=secondary_categories, lazy='dynamic')

    def categories(self):
        return [self.primary_category] + self.secondary_categories.all()
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more code as well as the full stack trace. As it stands, nothing in your code uses the 'category' attribute and is therefore not directly related to the Exception.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake when copying the error... its actually categories() which is causing the error, which is used in the last print statement in the code example. I also added the Object class definition.

Comment: `categories` is not an attribute that can be lazy loaded, so the Exception is referring to something else. Please post the full stack trace. It is also not clear what `models.Table` is in relation to `Object`.

Comment: hi univerio... Does it refer to self.secondary_categories.all() with has a lazy=dynamic load? I changed the name of the Table to Table from Object...

Comment: I added the full stack trace...

Comment: This code in isolation should work. Unfortunately, this means that some other parts of your code is messing with the session or instance in a way that is not intended. In order for us to help you debug this issue, you need to distill your code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (By going through this exercise you might even be able to find the issue yourself.)